# Jenkins in progress build shows status color from last (failed) build

Tags: jenkins

When we rebuild a failed build, Jenkins shows the new build with a red status icon while it's in progress, until it finishes successfully at which point it changes to green. Why is that? It seems unhelpful. Why not just an indeterminate in-progress color like blue?

[image]

PS. The job is a freestyle job building on MacOS.

Comment: It might not make much sense in the perspective of the "Build History" since you can see the prior run status anyway, but the (same) status is reflected in the Job run status page (aka Dashboard) (ie: click on that link), plus in the main job page, folders and views. The fact that is is blinking tells you it's running. [BLUE is the the colour of never built/first build](https://ci.jenkins.io/legend). An indeterminate colour conveys no extra information, whereas the colour of the last build does generally convey useful information; the status of the last build & there's a new one in progress.

Comment: I suppose, but I just find it deceptive. My colleague assumed it had already failed since it was red.

Comment: It seems pretty clear when you [look at the legend](https://ci.jenkins.io/legend); not sure what else to add. Personally, I'd rather see they fix up the [weather symbols](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-65124) first!